# Creating a new Cocoapod: use example project for remote repo?

Tags: ios, xcode, github, cocoapods

I'm trying to create a new pod (Cocoapod) for an iOS library and have followed the tutorial instructions at https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create.  I currently don't have a remote repo, but have a local project with git history.  After running the `pod lib create` command (running Cocoapods v.0.37.2), and opening up the resultant project, it looks similar to the example pictured on the above tutorial link:

[image]

My questions are:

1. As I don't have my project hosted remotely (i.e., Github), and referencing the image above, should I use the `Example for MyLib` part for my remote repo, obviously adding anything else to it that I would need? If so, how should I include my library that I want to make into a pod? I noticed that the example project was initialized as a git repo.  **Edit:** I did see on http://nshipster.com/cocoapods/ that invoking `pod try` will use the created example project, so I'm guessing I should use the created example project for my remote repo if I want that feature?
2. Or should I configure my pre-existing `MyLib` project with the newly created podspec file, etc, and push that to my remote repo, following the instructions at https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html?

Under "Making a Demo Application" on the `pod lib create` tutorial link it's stated:

"The template will generate an Xcode project for your library. This means you don't have to go through creating a new project in Xcode.

If you want to have an example project for pod try MyLib or need to have your library's tests run inside an application ( interaction tests, custom fonts, etc ) then you should say yes. A good metric is "Should this Pod include a screenshot?"; if so, then you should have a demo."

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After doing more research and trying a few things out, I ended up going with my first option: using the example project created by the `pod lib create` command.  From consulting numerous sources and tutorials, I found this one to be the most accurate and helpful in this process (at least at the time of this being written): ["Your First CocoaPod"](http://code.dblock.org/2014/03/02/your-first-cocoapod.html).

Specifically, the line:

> Add the Demo/Pods folder, which includes all the pods installed from pod install, to .gitignore.

addressed one of my concerns about what to do with the `Pods` folder.  After that, I was able to push my example project to my remote repo, and then ultimately to publish my pod.  In summary, it appears I could have either used the `pod lib create` command to create my example project, or generated a `podspec` file manually to be used with my pre-existing library that contained a sample project.